# JQuery toggleClass not firing

Tags: jquery

I have a simple page which has lots of elements with the same class.

When a button is clicked within one of the elements I want to apply a class to all other elements which effectively dims them using opacity.

This is what I'm trying but it's not adding the classes:

CSS:

```
.act { width:100px; border:1px solid green; padding:20px; }
.actDim { opacity:0.5; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="act actID1">
    <button class="btn btn-success enquireAct" id="1">Click</button>
</div>
<div class="act actID2">
    <button class="btn btn-success enquireAct" id="2">Click</button>
</div>
<div class="act actID3">
    <button class="btn btn-success enquireAct" id="3">Click</button>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.enquireAct', function() {
    var actID = $(this).attr('id');
    $('[class^="actID"]').removeClass('actDim'); // remove from all classes to start with
    $('[class^="actID"]').not('.actID' + actID).addClass('actDim'); // add to everything but this
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darrensw/tsjGY/2/)

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `attribute starts with` selector, the target elements' class attribute start with `act` not `actID` so the query returns an empty collection, you can use the `attribute contains` selector instead:

```
$('[class*="actID"]');
```

But why not using the `.parent()` method?

```
$(this).parent('.act');
```

Then for selecting the siblings of the parent element you can use the `siblings` method.

edit: I had forgotten to mention that you haven't loaded jQuery in your fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/yJ7Jd/

Please note that `attribute *` selectors are very *expensive*, I'd suggest using the `parent` and `siblings` methods:

```
$(this).parent('.act')
       .removeClass('actDim')
       .siblings('.act')
       .addClass('actDim');
```

Comment: there's two classes on each element act and actID*, I thought it easier to ignore the one I was in doing it that way

Comment: so basically this answer is incorrect is what I'm saying

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Isn't this what you are trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/yJ7Jd/

Comment: Exactly that, thank you - add it as an answer and I can accept

Comment: @DarrenSweeney You are welcome, actually that's my initial/current answer without a demo, I'll add the demo.

Comment: Thanks again, that works even better, had to go a few rounds with parents but priceless advice, much appreciated.